# Unity OverlapCircle radius detecting wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, move, radius

I have set a radius for my OverlapCircle at .2f
It doesn't need to be huge as it is simply detecting if a grid on my tilemap is a wall. OverlapCircle seems to not find any wall layers at a radius below .5f. At .5f it finds a wall and stops movement but in a square where there is no wall layer.

```
if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) == 1f)
            {
                Debug.Log(movePoint.position + new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, 0));
                if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, 0), detectRadius, moveBlockers))                
                {
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, 0);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Got any scaling going on?

Comment: Not that I can find. The radius is set in a public value and not altered anywhere

Comment: How are you setting the mask layers?

Comment: My LayerMask is only looking for layer "Wall". I have set only one Tilemap to this layer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Composite Collider Geometry Type to "Polygons"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).